# UICollectionView Detecting Scroll direction and Changing Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView to create a swipe similar to a Tinder Swipe. 
I want to detect the scroll direction when the user starts dragging before the new page (card) is displayed. When it is detected it should set the image to Thumbs up(right swipe) or thumbs down(left swipe).

Now i use scrollViewWillBeginDragging and it almost works with comparing contentOffset but this is not what i am looking for since it displays the image to late.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

    var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "profil"), UIImage(named: "profil"),UIImage(named: "profil"),UIImage(named: "profil"),UIImage(named: "profil"),UIImage(named: "profil"),UIImage(named: "profil")]

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbImage: UIImageView!
    var currentPage = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        cell.imgImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 0 ? .red : .green

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    } 


    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        var page = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)

        if(page > currentPage)
        {
            thumbImage.isHidden = false
            thumbImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thumbsup")
            print("RIGHT")
        } else {
            thumbImage.isHidden = false
            thumbImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thumbsdown")
            print("LEFT")
        }

        currentPage = page

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation the thumb image is shown only when the page changes which would be when the swiping is half way through. I would  separate the page changing from the thumb showing. Pseudo code:

```
if (currentOffset > lastOffset) {
    showThumbsUp()
}
else {
    showThumbsDown()
}

page = ...
if (page != currentPage) {
    changePage(page)
    lastOffset = currentOffset
}
```

Comment: How can i get the value of currentOffset and lastOffset?

Comment: You can get the current offset from scrollView.contentOffset.x and
lastOffset will be a variable that you maintain

Comment: would using panGestureRecognizer be a good idea to solve this?

Comment: You get the offset directly from the UIScrollView, why do you need access to the gesture recognizer?